# SQL Server procedure update and coalesce issue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, updates, coalesce

So I am making a very simple update procedure, like I have done before, but when I run the execution through it, it does not update. I have looked this over several times and do not see any error in why it wouldn't cause the update to pass through it. My manual updates are working fine, so I am thinking I am either missing something super-obvious or this is something going on with the coalesce function. Any help would be great. The more eyes the merrier.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCreditCard
@CreditCardID INT,
@CardType nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CardNumber nvarchar(25) = NULL,
@ExpMonth tinyint = NULL,
@ExpYear smallint = NULL
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE [Sales].[CreditCard]
SET
    @CardType  = COALESCE(@CardType,CardType),
    @CardNumber  = COALESCE(@CardNumber,CardNumber),
    @ExpMonth  = COALESCE(@ExpMonth,ExpMonth),
    @ExpYear  = COALESCE(@ExpYear,ExpYear)
FROM Sales.CreditCard
WHERE @CreditCardID = CreditCardID
END
```

---

```
EXECUTE UpdateCreditCard 
@CreditCardID = 19267,
@CardType = 'MasterCard',
@CardNumber = '99999999',
@ExpMonth = 4,
@ExpYear = 2025
```

Comment: what happens when you run `select * FROM Sales.CreditCard
WHERE CreditCardID = 19267`. check whether any rows returned

Comment: It just returns the old data and none of the updated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating the `variables` not the `columns` in `CreditCard` table.

```
.....
SET
@CardType  = COALESCE(@CardType,CardType),   -- here you are updating the @CardType variable
.....
```

Try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCreditCard
@CreditCardID INT,
@CardType nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CardNumber nvarchar(25) = NULL,
@ExpMonth tinyint = NULL,
@ExpYear smallint = NULL
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE [Sales].[CreditCard]
SET
    CardType  = COALESCE(@CardType,CardType),
    CardNumber  = COALESCE(@CardNumber,CardNumber),
    ExpMonth  = COALESCE(@ExpMonth,ExpMonth),
    ExpYear  = COALESCE(@ExpYear,ExpYear)
FROM Sales.CreditCard
WHERE   CreditCardID=@CreditCardID
END
```

Comment: You sir are awesome, I looked it over and over not realizing I made the variables the update and not the columns. That worked like a charm. I will have to pay attention to to silly mistakes like that.

Comment: @MikeyZ - Everyone do these kind of mistakes. No need to use the word **sir** in `SO`